# How to create multiple partitions of the same size from command line?

Tags: linux, parted, partition-table, sfdisk

I need to create 20 partitions of the same size (cue to the first comment only the first 3 can be primary and the 4th needs to be extended an the other remaining 17 in it)

I tried:

```
for i in $(seq 1 20); do  echo 'start=2048, type=83' | sfdisk /dev/ram0p${i}; done
```

but doesn't work.

Is there a way to do it in Linux, using `parted`, `sfdisk` or other tool?
So at least is there a way to create the 17 logical partitions programatically?

Comment: Well, obviously all 20 partitions can't start on sector 2048, for one thing. You will also need to figure out how large the partitions should be, and pass that. Note also that DOS partition tables only support 4 primary partitions.

Comment: @wurtel that's the problem how do I calculated the offset

Answer (score 0):

1. use Ansible for the same. below is the ansible module for partition creation.

   - parted:
     device: /dev/sdb  # device details 
     number: 1   # this is number of partion. you can define numbers with varilabe from 1 to 20 #
     state: present
     part_end: 2GiB

   `parted: device: /dev/sdb number: "{{ item.num }}" state: present with_items: - {num : 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 .... till 20} - filesystem: fstype: ext2 dev: /dev/sdb"{{item.num}}" with_items: - {num : 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 .... till 20}`

Comment: Can you please write the final command

Comment: `- parted:
    device: /dev/sdb
    number: "{{ item.num }}"
    state: present
  with_items:
        - {num : 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 .... till 20}


- filesystem:
     fstype: ext2
     dev: /dev/sdb"{{item.num}}"
  with_items:
        - {num : 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 .... till 20}
`

Comment: I am not familiar with ansible how do you use this in command line?

Comment: ansible is used to orchestrate the configuration of a (large) number of systems from a central point, you can't use it to configure a local server like you want.